# Groovy Split not working as expected in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, split, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to split a string based on the delimiter "." (DOT) using the groovy split function in a **Jenkins pipeline** and I would like to assign the split sub strings to multiple variables in a single line. Following is the code that I have (It works in groovy) and I keep getting an error in Jenkins pipeline, what am I doing wrong here? Is there an alternative way to do this? Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

```
    IP="192.168.234.20"
    def (env.W, env.X, env.Y, env.Z) = IP.split('\\.')
    
    Error:
    WorkflowScript: 543: expecting an identifier, found ',' @ line 543, column 28.
     (env.W, env.X, env.Y, env.Z) = IP.split('\\.')
           ^
```

```
    IP="192.168.234.20"
    (env.W, env.X, env.Y, env.Z) = IP.split('\\.')
    
    Error:
    WorkflowScript: 543: expecting ')', found ',' @ line 543, column 24.
     (env.W, env.X, env.Y, env.Z) = IP.split('\\.')
           ^
```

Comment: What's the version of groovy? Try something simple as `def (a,b)=[11,22]` , try `def (W,X,Y,Z) = IP.split('\\.') as List`

Comment: I have it working on Groovy and know how to do it, the problem that I have is this doesn't work in Jenkins Groovy in a pipeline script.

Comment: i asked those to detect the limits of your jenkins...

Comment: Thank you daggett! The problem was the variables being env variables. I removed the env and your code works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define the variable `IP` and you can either use `split` or `tokenize`:
Below is a working example:

```
def IP = "192.168.234.20"
def (W,X,Y,Z) = IP.split('\\.')
                    println(W)
                    println(X)
                    println(Y)
                    println(Z)
// OR
def (A,B,C,D) = IP.tokenize('\\.')
                    println(A)
                    println(B)
                    println(C)
                    println(D)
```

Comment: I have it working on Groovy and know how to do it, the problem that I have is this doesn't work in Jenkins Groovy in a pipeline script.

Comment: @Jose i did this run on Pipeline script and it gives results.Did you use ``def IP``

Comment: Thank you Altaf! The problem was the variables being env variables. I removed the env and your above code works.